# Pass variable to macro when opening Word 2010 document via python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word, win32com

Using Python 2.7.8; Word 2010

I am running a Python script and executing a MS Word macro from within it. Below is the code that I use to do this.

I need to pass a variable (myVar) from the Python script to the Word macro but cannot figure out how to do it. The macro does different things depending on the value of the passed variable.

Suggestions anyone?

```
word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(myDir + "\\MyFile.docx") # pass myVar on open?
word.Run("executeMacros")
doc.Save()
doc.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the `myVar` variable as an argument in the `Run` method:

```
expression.Run(MacroName, varg1, varg2, varg3, ..., varg30)
word.Run("executeMacros",myVar)
```